# Access to iOS Messages via Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Does apple gives access to iOS Messages using swift? If it does are we allowed to delete messages? I searched this and all answers i found is 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has changed in the last 5 years - the answer is still No.

Comment: I understand the reasons behind this. I just hoped. Thank you :)